# Issue with hair particle disparity between Viewport and Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I'm new to the hair particle system in Blender and I'm currently just messing around with a practice render.

I have my hair how I want it in the viewport but when I render in Cycles the hair is all blown out and loses detail.

I've tried fidgeting with the settings to get it right but I've had no luck.

How can I fix it?

Render
[image]

Viewport
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the diameter scale being too high.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.